# inserting records in PostgreSQL using golang

Tags: go

I am using below goroutinue to inset record in PostgreSQL. After execution, I see records inserting twice. Any issue with below code ? can someone suggest.

```
func main() {
  // create the statement string
  var sStmt string = "INSERT INTO LOGINS (id,login_name,password)   values ($1, $2,$3)"

  psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
    "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
    host, port, user, password, dbname)
  db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)

  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  stmt, err := db.Prepare(sStmt)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  fmt.Printf("StartTime: %v\n", time.Now())

  res, err := stmt.Exec(2000,"test","test")
  fmt.Println("inserting")
  if err != nil || res == nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  stmt.Close()
  db.Close()

  fmt.Printf("StopTime: %v\n", time.Now())
}
```

Comment: You're calling `stmt.Close` twice and the first time you're calling it is before you're calling `stmt.Exec`, that doesn't seem right. Remove the first call, see what happens, and report back.

Comment: Sorry. its typo mistake. I have rectified now. If i use one close stmt, then also it is inserting records twice.

Comment: There is no goroutine in the code provided. Do you have duplication when runnning this `main()`? If yes I would try removing `stmt.Close()` first.

Comment: @sheik after update your code seems fine to me, but is this the whole code? Are you running it inside `main` like in the example or is the code inside some function or block that is being executed elsewhere in your program? Are you seeing the result of `fmt.Println("inserting")` printed twice in the console or only once? Did you try running the same query through pgsql?

Comment: Yes, I am running inside main. fmt.Println("inserting") is printing only once but records inserted twice in DB. and when i use the same insert query to run directly in DB then only 1 record inserted,